# Get user-logon-name

Tags: c#, ldap

Is there a way to retrive the "User logon name" with LDAP?

The "user logon name" looks like `{SamAccountName}@{DOMAIN}`, its **not** `DOMAIN\USER` (see image below).
Example: `admin@example.de`

[image]

Edit: I already read [How to retrieve SAMAccountName from Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112062/how-to-retrieve-samaccountname-from-active-directory). My question is diffrent because I dont want `DOMAIN\USER`. I want `user@domain` see my example on top.

Comment: Yes. There is...

Comment: Not `DOMAIN\USER`. :P

Comment: Is "USER" different in DOMAIN\USER and user@domain?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple LDAP- and Exchange-Servers. The format of the "user logon name" is diffrent for each instance.

Comment: Sometime its the fullname `surname.lastname@domain.com` and on other instance its `CN@domain.com`.

Comment: Current workaround: I try all formats that I know yet. Like a little brutforce-attack (If login at Exchange failed -> next). I hope someone has a better solution.